# How to get commit on a particular date using gitlabapi query?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I have seen that there is query to fetch commits using since or until in gitlabapi query. I want to fetch the response for a particular date.

Example: I want to fetch the response for a repository's commit on 2022-04-18. I have tried with the following query but the & operation didn't work
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/repository/commits?first_parent=true&**since=2022-04-18&until=2022-04-18**"

Response is displayed if I use:
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/repository/commits?first_parent=true&since=2022-04-18"

In this case, later dates commits are also displayed. I want to see only the commits on 2022-04-18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify the **until** and **since** in **ISO 8601** format.

To get a specific day you need to specify a day period e.g

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/repository/commits?first_parent=true&since=2022-04-18T00:00:00Z&until=2022-04-18T23:59:59Z"
```